# Asignar objeto de clase a otra con arraylist?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de una galeria de arte en java pero  estoy estancado en algo. Tengo una clase para la obra, otra para el artista, otra para el cliente y otra para compras. Entonces primero debo de asignar obras a artistas para que se sepa quien es el autor de la obra, tnego un arraylist de obras y otro de artistas.

Lo mismo me pasa para hacer una compra, debo ingresar el codigo del cliente y el codigo de la obra para asignar la compra de la obra al cliente y generar un codigo de compra aleatorio pero de nuevo no se como hacer esta asignacion.

he tratado de hacer la lista de compras como un arraylist de tipo object, algo así:

```
ArrayList<Object> datoscompra=new ArrayList<Object>();
public void ComprarObra(long codigoObra,long codigoCliente,Compra compra,Obra ob,Cliente cliente){
        char op;
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese codigo del cliente: ");
            codigoCliente = scan.nextLong();
        }while(ClienteValido(codigoCliente)!=true);
        
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese codigo de la obra: ");
            codigoObra=scan.nextLong();
        }while(NoExiste(codigoObra)!=true);
        for(Obra obra:listaobras){
            if(codigoObra==obra.getCodigoObra()){
                System.out.println("Titulo de la obra: "+obra.getTitulo());
                System.out.println("Precio de la obra: "+obra.getPrecioRef());
                
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
            System.out.println("Desea comprar esta obra?(s/n)");
            op = scan.next().charAt(0);
            if (op == 's') {
                Random random = new Random();
                int r=random.nextInt(9999999);
                if(!listacompras.contains(compra.getCodigoCompra())){
                    compra.setCodigoCompra(r);
                }
                System.out.println("Codigo de compra: " + compra.getCodigoCompra());
                compra.setPagado(true);
                if (!listacompras.contains(compra)) {
                    compra = new Compra(compra);
                    this.listacompras.add(compra);
                    this.datoscompra.add(compra);
                    this.datoscompra.add(cliente);
                    this.datoscompra.add(ob);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Compra cancelada");
            }
        }
    }
```

Pero creo que esto no ha funcionado porque ademas luego debo imprimir una lista de las compras hechas mostrando los codigos de las compras, los datos de los clientes y de las obras.

Basicamente no he sabido asignar una clase o sus datos a otra.

¿Como podria hacer esta asignacion? Me está comiendo la cabeza esto.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Qué diferencia hay entre poner `setTitulo("titulo")` y `setObra(obra)`?? En la clase que quieras guardar otra simplemente en vez de ponerle un atributo `private String titulo`  ponle uno `private Obra obra` o `private Obra[] compras` o lo que te apetezca. Es exactamente lo mismo asignar un string que asignar cualquier otra clase.

Comment: @Benito-B pero es que no puedo ponerle atributos de clase a otras clases, todo lo debo trabajar en mi clase controlador que es donde están todas las funciones, las otras son entidades nada más.